# Ansi C - Removing new line character and changing it to a space

Tags: c, delimiter

```
    void createTextFile()
{
    FILE *textFile = fopen("/Users/Trenae_Alyxandria_Johnson/Desktop/myTextFile.txt", "w");
    char c; 
    fputs("1\n2\n3\n4\n5", textFile);
    fclose(textFile);

    textFile = fopen("/Users/Trenae_Alyxandria_Johnson/Desktop/myTextFile.txt", "r");
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        c = fgetc(textFile);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if(c(i) == '\n')
        {
            c(i) = ' ';
        }
    }

    printf("%c" , c);
    fclose(textFile);
}
```

I'm trying to remove the new line char and change it to a space. I know it's not an array but I guess I'm asking how do I parse through the file, to see when I get to the new line then remove it and replace it with a space so the 1 - 5 that was first entered can now appear on one line with a space char separating each. 
ERRORS:

error: subscripted
      value is not an array, pointer, or vector
        if(c[i] == '\n')

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to change the file content or print it to `stdout` after modifying it.

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`, and you're comparing `c` to `EOF` before you've initialized it. The correct way to write the loop is: `int c; while ((c = fgetc(txtFile)) != EOF) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop is not needed. You can remove it. `

```
 c = fgetc(textFile);
 while (c != EOF){
    if(c == '\n')
    {
        c = ' ';
    }
    printf("%c" , c);
    c = fgetc(textFile);
 }
```

A `char` is not a string, a char is a character. So `c[i]` does not mean anything. It you wish to store a string, use an array of char terminated by `\0` :

```
 char s[100];
 s[99]='\0'
 printf("%s",s);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int c;//return of fgetc type is int

while(EOF!=(c=fgetc(textFile)))
    putchar(c == '\n' ? ' ' : c);
```